# qemuはマルチコアでのosの起動に対応していませんか?

Tags: qemu

先日、armのシングルボードコンピュータにqemuをインストールして、"i386用"のdebianのインストーラーを起動しようと思ったのですが、起動はするもののcpuを1コアしか使っていないようで、とても遅いです。マルチコアでosを起動することはできませんか?

アーキテクチャはarm64(aarch64?)でCortex A-53です。 osがubuntu bionic で、qemuは、aptから、インストールしました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ゲストとホストのアーキテクチャによります](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42261937/5989200)が、組み合わせによってはマルチコアで起動できます。この際、[`-smp` オプション](http://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html#Standard-options)でエミュレートするコア数を設定できます。

今回はゲストが i386 でホストが aarch64 ということですが、 https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/tcg-multithread と[現状のソースコード](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/04bb7fe2bf55bdf66d5b7a5a719b40bbb4048178/tcg/aarch64/tcg-target.h#L139)を見るに、まだサポートされていません。

Comment: 例えば、4コアcpuで、そのうち2コア使いたかったら、
qemu-system-i386 -hda hdd.img -cdrom debian-9.4.0-i386-netinst.iso -boot d -m 1024 -smp 2
でよろしいのですか?

Comment: @wanwansan アーキテクチャにもよりますが、それでいけるはずです。オプションについては https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/QEMU/Options の方が一覧として見やすいかもしれません。

Comment: 試してみましたが、cpuを1コアしか使っていない感じです。
アーキテクチャはarm64(aarch64?)でCortex A-53です。
osがubuntu bionic で、qemuは、aptから、インストールしたのですが、それが悪いのでしょうか?
エラーなどは一切出ていないようです。

Comment: @wanwansan むむ、すいません、こちらが良く理解できていなかったかもしれません。変な挙動をするかもしれませんが、`--accel tcg,thread=multi` で動作したりはしませんか？ ( https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/tcg-multithread を参考にしています。)

Comment: @wanwansan いや、デフォルトで1コアしか使われていない時点で、お使いの QEMU ではサポートされていないということですよね、すいません。

Comment: うーん、やっぱり無理ですね。
もしかしたらソースからビルドする必要があるもしれませんね。。。
osを起動せずに、exeファイルだけを実行することはできるのでしょうか?

Comment: @wanwansan 用途が分かりませんが、OS ではなく i386 向けのソフトウェアが利用したいということであればクロス・コンパイルしか思いつきません……。あまりお役に立てそうにないです。

Comment: ありがとうございました!!!!